# How do I pass the graveyard stage in Battleground Z?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass-zombies-battleground-z

Level 3-2 in Streetpass Zombies (a.k.a. Battleground Z) has you inside a graveyard, where you have to protect its two gates from zombies. The gates are on opposite sides.

Even if I find several Miis with whom I can team up, and leave some of them posted by one gate while I defend the other one, they eventually give up and come back to me. As they take time to walk up to me, may get trapped behind an obstacle on the way and it also takes time for me to walk between gates, one of the gates remains undefended for several seconds when this happens.

In the 3rd wave of zombies both gates are attacked by very strong zombies and as a result whichever one is undefended goes down before I can reach the zombie attacking it, after the Miis I posted there leave.

Is there a trick to beating this stage? Is it possible to ensure that Miis I post somewhere do not abandon their post?

Comment: Maybe the trick is using the milk delivery zombie, I've just tried the same level (with just the lame Piggy-bank) and they've destroyed a gate before I did anything. Those bomb zombies are too strong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just beaten that level.

My strategy is to beat the first and second wave with normal attacks. If you have different weapons, use them. You should defeat these 2 waves without getting too many damage on the gates. (I suggest you use the WiiMote, it's pretty fast.)

For the 3rd wave, use 1-2 charged attacks on the incoming zombies, then the **Milk Delivery** zombie should spawn. Defeat it, get the Milk bottle and knock out each zombie that's facing you, then run towards a gate while the effect is still active and clear the area. When the Milk effect wears off, run towards the other gate and use another charged attack to defeat every enemy left.

That's it. I made it without any helping Miis, just a couple of weapons.

Comment: It took a few tries, but this helped. I hadn't seen the milk zombie before this answer.

Comment: @GeorgeT He's very useful, there's one in each level and he usually comes in the third zombie wave